# Virtualbox: install a x64 Windows OS from Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I was thinking about making a Virtual Machine, but the description of VirtualBox from the Software installer say:

> VirtualBox is a free x86 virtualization solution allowing a wide range
>   of x86 operating systems such as Windows, DOS, BSD or Linux to run on
>   a Linux system.

Can I once installed, use a x64 Windows 10 distribution or must I use a x86 os?

Comment: Aboslutely you can use 64bit OSes. Just need VT-x enabled in bios and 64bit CPU.

Answer (score 3):

You need a `x86-64` CPU, kernel, and version of virtual-box. If your Ubuntu is 64bit then just install virtual-box and go.

The confusion is that Microsoft call the `x86-64` an `x64`. This is wrong. The name `x86` comes from a generalisation of the various CPUs in the series: `8086`, `80286`, `80386`, `80486`, `80586` (pentium), `80686` … where the prefix is represented as an `x`.

Virtual box is using `x86` to mean `x86-32` and `x86-64`. Originally it referred to just 32bit as that was all there was. They left it as it was, because it was not wrong. The are distinguishing from other CPU types (arm, sparc, alpha, 68000, power, …), not between 32/64 bit.